# AttributeError: 'izdanie' object has no attribute 'kniga_iz'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
class kniga(object):
    def name(self, i, kniga_name):
        self.i = i
        self.kniga_name = kniga_name
        self.kniga_name[self.i] = input("Введите имя автора")
    def surname(self,i, kniga_surname):
        self.i = i
        self.kniga_surname = kniga_surname
        self.kniga_surname[self.i] = input("Введите фамилию ")
    def year(self, i, kniga_year):
        self.i = i
        self.kniga_year = kniga_year
        self.kniga_year [self.i] = int(input("Введите год"))
    def izdatelstvo(self, i, kniga_izdatelstvo):
        self.i = i
        kniga.kniga_izdatelstvo = kniga_izdatelstvo
        self.kniga_izdatelstvo[self.i] = input("Введите издательство")

class statia(object):
    def name(self):
        print("Ввдите имя автора")
        statia.surname(self)
    def surname(self):
        statia.year(self)
    def year(self):
        statia.izdatelstvo(self)
    def izdatelstvo(self):
        print("Класс статья работает нормально")
class resurs(object):
    def name(self):
        print("Ввдите имя автора")
        resurs.surname(self)
    def surname(self):
        resurs.ssilka(self)
    def ssilka(self):
        resurs.anotacia(self)
    def anotacia(self):
        print("Класс ресурс работает нормально")
class izdanie(object):
    def kniga(self):
        kol_knig = int(input("Введите колличество книг, которое вы хотите добавить в список"))
        kniga_name = [None] * kol_knig
        kniga_surname = [None] * kol_knig
        kniga_year = [None] * kol_knig
        kniga_izdatelstvo = [None] * kol_knig
        for i in range(kol_knig):
            kniga.name(self, i, kniga_name)
            kniga.surname(self, i, kniga_surname)
            kniga.year(self, i, kniga_year)
            kniga.izdatelstvo(self, i, kniga_izdatelstvo)

        sys.exit()
    def statia(self):
        kol_statei = int(input("Введите колличество статей, которое вы хотите добавить в список"))
        for i in range(kol_statei):
            statia.name(self)
        sys.exit()
    def resurs(self):
        kol_resursov = int(input("Введите колличество ресурсов, которое вы хотите добавить в список"))
        for i in range(kol_resursov):
            resurs.name(self)
        sys.exit()
q = izdanie()
print("""
В соответствии с вашими пожелениями выберить пункт
1.Создать список книг.
2.Создать список статей.
3.Создать список ресурсов.
""")
choose = 0
while 1 >= choose <= 3:
    choose = int(input())
    if choose == 1:
        q.kniga()
    elif choose == 2:
        q.statia()
    elif choose == 3:
        q.resurs()
    else:
        print("Выберите другой номер, введенный вами номер отсутствует в списке")
```

Comment: Это загадка такая? понять, где у вас ошибка а потом понять, почему она у вас?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, у вас пока вообще ничего не будет работать. Начните с элементарного:

- Названия классов должны быть с большой буквы! Сейчас у вас невозможно понять: где в коде название класса, а где экземпляра класса. Методы классов у вас называются так же, как [другие] классы, из-за этого совсем ничего непонятно, всё перепутано. Разница хотя бы в больших-маленьких буквах уже что-то позволит понять.
- Почитайте про инкапсуляцию. Вы должны осознать, что экземпляр класса `Kniga` должен содержать один (!!!) объект типа "книга", в котором должны быть поля "Автор", "Год", "Название". Сам класс "Книга" ничего не должен знать про список книг, про это должен знать какой-то более высокоуровневый класс, например, "Библиотека". Поля класса обычно задаются сразу при создании объекта класса, в методе `__init__`, реализуйте его для вашего класса.
- Стройте иерархию классов от простого к сложному. Сначала правильно напишите класс `Kniga`. Он должен позволять создать одну книгу с определёнными полями, например так: `kniga = Kniga("Виктор Пелевин", 1999, "Generation П")`. И хорошо бы если бы класс мог уметь печатать информацию о себе, для этого реализуйте метод `__str__`. Сразу протестируйте этот класс - создайте одну книгу, сделайте `print` от неё, чтобы посмотреть, что поля правильно заполнились. Потом создайте две книги и напечатайте инфу о них. Потом переходите к другим классам, которые уже будут использовать класс `Kniga`.

Так вы постепенно разберётесь, как правильно описывать классы. А если сейчас кто-то за вас всё напишет, вы так и не разберётесь, что такое классы и как их писать.